# Return a Boolean instead of the whole collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The `Stack` model can have "user progress", users can "clear" stacks. And that progress is stored in the `Progress` model.

`Progress` model:

```
public function stack(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Stack::class);
}
```

It would be neat if it was possible to fetch all stacks, and if the user has "cleared" it or not, with a boolean true or false. I don't won't to fetch all data corresponding to the progress. So I have tried setting up a "finished" relation on the `Stack` model

```
public function finished(){
    return $this->hasOne(Progress::class) ? true : false;
}
```

But this setup gives me the following error
`Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on boolean`.

This is how I call the relationship at the moment

```
    $user = \App\Stack::with(['finished' => function($q){
        return $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
    }])->get();
```

But that returns the whole collection, and that is not necessary. The expected result should be like:

```
{
"id": 5,
"user_id": 2,
"subject_id": 2,
"name": "tstar igen",
"slug": "tstar-igen",
"description": "asdasd",
"image": null,
"created_at": "2017-10-06 08:27:36",
"updated_at": "2017-10-06 08:27:36",
"finished": true/false
},
```

So lets say that here is an relation entry in in the progress table for the stack above.

```
+----+---------+----------+
| id | user_id | stack_id |
+----+---------+----------+
|  1 |       1 |        5 |
+----+---------+----------+
```

So when fetching the stacks, with relation finish. The `finished` column should be true or false. So the return from `Stack`, with relation `finished` should be like the following. Notice the finished column changed to false on the last stack, because the relation is not present in the progress table.

```
{
"id": 5,
"user_id": 2,
"subject_id": 2,
"name": "tstar igen",
"slug": "tstar-igen",
"description": "asdasd",
"image": null,
"created_at": "2017-10-06 08:27:36",
"updated_at": "2017-10-06 08:27:36",
"finished": true
},
{
"id": 6,
"user_id": 2,
"subject_id": 2,
"name": "another stack",
"slug": "another-stack",
"description": "This is a test stack for all the stacks out there",
"image": null,
"created_at": "2017-10-06 08:27:36",
"updated_at": "2017-10-06 08:27:36",
"finished": false
},
```

Comment: could you explain better from your question what you are trying to achieve? You want to filter all stacks where user's 'finished' status is either 'true' or 'false'?

Comment: Edited my question with more information

Answer (score 2):

You can try `withCount` that counts your related models. But it will return number of related models not boolean. Here is an example:

**Stack.php**

```
public function progress(){
    return $this->hasOne(Progress::class);
}
```

then:

```
 \App\Stack::withCount('progress')->get();
```

Now results have `count_progress` attribute with number of related 'Progress' models. Because your relation is `hasOne` it should be 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost done, You have your relationship setup well except for the boolean stuffs, remove it:

```
public function finished(){
    return $this->hasOne(Progress::class);
}
```

Then when you need to check you can use `has` or `whereHas` relationship method:

```
$stack = \App\Stack::whereHas('finished', function($q){
    return $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id);
})->get();
```

Based on your need thats the best I could conceive. I think this should be sufficient.

It would do well to learn how [has and whereHas](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) works. But just to summarize: `has` simply is like `whereHas` except that it checks if there is at least one model related to the first model, and the other helps you to make more advanced constraints as shown in the example I gave.

Comment: Thanks for your response! But, I'm trying to build and API for the stack model, so I can track user progression. So need all stacks, and if they are finished or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Your model**

```
public function progress(){
    return $this->hasOne(Progress::class);
}
```

**Your controller**

```
...
$stacks->load('progress');
```

**resource**

```
'finished' => $this->whenLoaded('progress')->isNotEmpty()
```